# android environment variable :: user profile file or something?

Tags: android

i want to change application user's environment variable(suppose that i have root permission).    how does 'application user'(like app_0, app_1...) load their environment variable? in ubuntu for example, i could change environment variable via .bashrc or /etc/profile or etc. where is user profile file like .bashrc for app_X user?

```
# su app_0
$ export
ANDROID_ASSETS
ANDROID_BOOTLOGO
ANDROID_DATA
ANDROID_PROPERTY_WORKSPACE
ANDROID_ROOT
ASEC_MOUNTPOINT
BOOTCLASSPATH
EXTERNAL_STORAGE
LD_LIBRARY_PATH
LOOP_MOUNTPOINT
PATH
PWD
$ echo ~
~
$ echo $PATH
/sbin:/vendor/bin:/system/sbin:/system/bin:/system/xbin
$ echo $PWD
/data/data
$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/vendor/lib:/system/lib
$ cd ~
cd: can't cd to ~
$
```

Comment: Do you have access as root? Generally there is a file by the name of init.rc which has global exported environment variables. If you set it there, it should be available to all. You can find this file in the root directory of the android file system.

Comment: @VendettaDroid thx, but where is it ? i can't find it

Comment: If you have device/emulator then connect(in case of emulator, just start the emulator) it to the computer and then you can execute a command like "adb shell" without quotes. This will take you inside your android file system. There you can see this file init.rc. Just type "ls" command to get the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no per-user variable in Android. You can change the global ones by modifying the boot script(s), but that might have undesired effects, unless you are simply adding a new one.  `init*` files are generally in `/`.